# How to add products to cart one by one for each option?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, opencart

I spend some few hours and tried many things, but doesn't work. 
I'm modifying `Add to basket` of OpenCart 3 as shown in this picture:

[image]

Current Result:

[image]

Expected Result:
I want to have Product - Options 1 - Option 2 per each line in shopping cart.

[image]

I want to add each option and its related product one by one, not one product and all its options together at once. To do this I have these codes:

This is my unrendered code for checkbox:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" 
                     data-input-group="chart-group-{{ option.product_option_id }}-{{ option_value.product_option_value_id }}" 
                     id="option-{{ option.product_option_id }}-{{ option_value.product_option_value_id }}" 
                     name="option[{{ option.product_option_id }}][]" 
                     value="{{ option_value.product_option_value_id }}" 
                     class="chart-group" />
        {% if option_value.image %} <img src="{{ option_value.image }}" alt="{{ option_value.name }} {% if option_value.price %} {{ option_value.price_prefix }} {{ option_value.price }} {% endif %}" class="img-thumbnail" /> {% endif %}                  
        {{ option_value.name }}
    </label>
</div>
```

Rendered JS and HTML:

```js
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
    $(".chart-group:input:checked").each(function () {
      group_id = $(this).data('input-group');
        $('#input-quantity').val(
            $('input[name=quantity][data-input-group=' + group_id + ']').val()
        );
        
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: $('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select, #product textarea')
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="form-group required ">
  <div id="input-option229">
   <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="53">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td><div class="checkbox">
       <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-input-group="chart-group-229-26" id="option-229-26" name="option[229][]" value="26" class="chart-group">
        70B </label>
      </div></td>
     <td><input type="text" data-input-group="chart-group-229-26" name="quantity" value="0" size="2" id="input-quantity-229-26" class="qty text-center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><div class="checkbox">
       <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-input-group="chart-group-229-27" id="option-229-27" name="option[229][]" value="27" class="chart-group">
        75B </label>
      </div></td>
     <td><input type="text" data-input-group="chart-group-229-27" name="quantity" value="0" size="2" id="input-quantity-229-27" class="qty text-center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><div class="checkbox">
       <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-input-group="chart-group-229-28" id="option-229-28" name="option[229][]" value="28" class="chart-group">
        80B </label>
      </div></td>
     <td><input type="text" data-input-group="chart-group-229-28" name="quantity" value="0" size="2" id="input-quantity-229-28" class="qty text-center"></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <button type="button" id="button-cart" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="button-cart btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add to Cart</button>
   <input type="hidden" name="quantity" id="input-quantity" value="0">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Any kind helps is highly appreciated!

Comment: Hi a little bit complex to understand as we don't known if you got response on the ajax call and how you parse html if is a redirection or an ajax parse didn't show any success anonymous function and if the page.php index.php?route=checkout/cart/add do the job as split 2 different products cos isn't the same size thanks to clarify this point. Regards

Comment: @headmax I can provide FTP info if you're interested in. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: ok in private i am new here so if you drive me it will be good.

Comment: @headmax Thanks a lot! I fixed the problem. It was about JQuery.

Comment: hi sorry to the answer i am done now :), cos at work ...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

```
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {

  $(".iqty:input:text").each(function () {
    $('.chart-group:input:checkbox').prop("checked", false);

    if ($(this).val() > 0) {
        group_id = $(this).data('input-group');
        $('input[type=checkbox][data-input-group=' + group_id + ']').prop("checked", true);
        $('#input-quantity').val(
            $('input[name=quantity][data-input-group=' + group_id + ']').val()
        );

        $('input[name=quantity][data-input-group=' + group_id + ']').val(0)
    } else {
        $('#input-quantity').val(0);
    }
```

...